# How to determine if an existing class can be unit-tested?

Tags: c++, unit-testing

Recently, i took ownership of some c++ code. I am going to maintain this code, and add new features later on.
I know many people say that it is usually not worth adding unit-tests to existing code, but i would still like to add some tests which will at least partially cover the code. In particular, i would like to add tests which reproduce bugs which i fixed.

Some of the classes are constructed with some pretty complex state, which can make it more difficult to unit-test.

I am also willing to refactor the code to make it easier to test.

Is there any good article you recommend on guidelines which help to identify classes which are easier to unit-test? Do you have any advice of your own?

Comment: "I know many people say that it is usually not worth adding unit-tests to existing code..." <- you need to pick different people to listen to.  Just sayin'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While Martin Fowler's book on refactoring is a treasure trove of information, why not take a look at "[Working Effectively with Legacy Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131177052)."

Also, if you're going to be dealing with classes where there's a ton of global variables or huge amounts of state transitions I'd put in a lot of integration checks.  Separate out as much of the code which interacts with the code you're refactoring to make sure that all expected inputs in the order they are recieved continue to produce the same outputs.  This is critical as it's very easy to "fix" a subtle bug that might have been addressed somewhere else.

Take notes too.  If you do find that there is a bug which another function/class expects and handles properly you'll want to change both at the same time.  That's difficult unless you keep thorough records.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably the code was written for a purpose, and a unit test will check if the purpose is met, i.e. the pre-conditions and post-conditions hold for the methods.

If the public class methods are such that you can externally check the state it can be unit tested easily enough (black-box test). If the class state is invisible or if you have to test tricky private methods, your test class may need to be a friend (white-box test).

A class that is hard to unit test will be one that

- Has enormous dependencies, i.e. tightly coupled
- Is intended to work in a high-volume or multi-threaded environment. There you would use a system test rather than a unit test and the actual output may not be totally determinate.

Answer (score 1):

I written a fair number of blog posts about unit testing, non-trivial, C++ code: http://www.lenholgate.com/blog/2004/05/practical-testing.html

I've also written quite a lot about adding tests to existing code: http://www.lenholgate.com/blog/testing/

Answer (score 0):

Almost everything can and should be unit tested. If not directly, then by using mock classes.

Since you decided to refactor your classes, try to use BDD or TDD approach.

To prevent breaking existing functionality, the only way is to have good integration tests, but usually it takes time to execute them all for a complex system.

Without more details on what you do, it is not that easy to give more implementation details. Some are :

- use MVP or presenter first for developing gui
- use design patterns where appropriate
- use function and member pointers, or observer design pattern to break dependencies

Comment: The solution usually lies in deploying lots of TLAs

Comment: @CashCow TLAs? What does a TLA stands for?

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you're having to come up with some "measure" to test if a class is testable, you're already fscked.  You should be able to tell just by looking at it: can you write an independent program that links to this class alone and makes sure it works?

If a class is too huge so that you can't be sure just by looking at it...chances are it probably isn't testable.  People that don't know how to make small, distinct interfaces generally don't know how to adhere to any other principle either.

In the end though, the way to find out if a class is testable is to try to put it in a harness.  If you end up having to pull in half your program to do it, try refactoring.  If you find that you can't even perform the most basic refactor without having to rewrite the entire program, analyze the expense of doing so.

Answer (score 0):

We at IPL published a paper [It's testing Jim, but not as we know it](http://www.ipl.com/pdf/p0832.pdf) which explores the practical problems of testing C++ and suggests some techniques to address them that may well be of use given your question. These techniques are also well supported in Cantata++ - our C/C++ unit and integration testing tool.